# "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" creating table

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm getting my feet wet with Go 1.11 and postgres.

```
package db

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq" //database connector
    g "app/globalvariables"
)

func CreateTable(tid int) {
s := "CREATE TABLE someschema.sometable" + string(tid) + "(id serial PRIMARY KEY,...);"
    db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", "user="+g.DB_USER+" dbname="+g.DB_NAME+" sslmode=disable")
    defer db.Close()
    q, _ := db.Prepare(s)
    q.Exec()
}
```

When testing the function I get:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x51d46a]
```

What can it be?

Comment: Check the errors, is anything failing?

Comment: (1) Stop ignoring error returns. (2) `'schema'` is a string literal in SQL, you'd want to say `"schema"` if you need to quote the schema name.

Comment: @Dani Hi. Yes, the error is what i put, invalid mem address.

Comment: @muistooshort ignored them in code but when writing the test function i put them verbose. Will change the "schema" to someschema so it wont bring confusion. Thanks.

Comment: What statement in your code causes that panic? Also please put error handling nevertheless.

Comment: @zerkms r, err := q.Exec()

Comment: Please check your errors first then and update your code correspondingly

Comment: Looks like your `Prepare` call erred and gave you a nil `q`. What error does it return?

Comment: @RickyA thanks Rick, i was having an issue with string(tid). Integers cant be converted to string like that! (strconv.Iota must be used).

Comment: (hopefully) lessons learned: **always** to check errors

Comment: ok, so the lesson learned is: always, always test every error and never ever ignore then silently.

Answer (score 1):

I was wronly converting an integer to string with "string". I must use strconv.Iota.

Comment: Not that, you were not checking errors in the very first place